# How to show the specific item add/remove position in recyclerview

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, scroll-position

I've implemented the `RecyclerView` concept in studio and am working on adding methods like add and remove items in `RecyclerView` and it works fine.

**My question :** while am press the add `Button` it adds but as a user am not aware of that where it is actually add, in my code am give the position at 1 as static and am scrolled to bottom and click the add button means am not able to know whether it is add or not once am scroll to top only its known. so for this we can able to move the scroll position to the specific item add position during **add/remove** has been taken.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we want to show the exact place of the item is add/removed by scroll the position using following property

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(1);